# How can I change message in DuplexSessionChannel (tcpTransport) in WCF custom channel?

Tags: wcf, caching, duplex-channel

I implement IDuplexSessionChannel on my Custom Channel because I use tcpTransport. In that custom channel, I cache service call response(client side caching). But it has errors. In IRequestChannel it works fine. How can I change message in TryMessage method. My code :

```
public Message Receive(TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        Message response = null;
        response = CommunicationCacheManager.Get(_request.Headers.Action, _request);

        if (response == null)
        {
            response = this.InnerChannel.Receive(timeout);
            int cacheTimeout = 0;
            if (response.Headers.FindHeader(Constants.CacheTimeOutHeader.NAME, Constants.CacheTimeOutHeader.NAMESPACE) > -1)
            {
                cacheTimeout = response.Headers.GetHeader<int>(Constants.CacheTimeOutHeader.NAME, Constants.CacheTimeOutHeader.NAMESPACE);
            }
            if (cacheTimeout > 0 && response != null &&
                    !response.IsFault &&
                    !response.IsEmpty)
            {
                CommunicationCacheManager.Add(_request.Headers.Action, cacheTimeout, ref response);
            }
        }
        return response;
    }

    public Message Receive()
    {
        return this.InnerChannel.Receive();
    }

    public bool TryReceive(TimeSpan timeout, out Message message)
    {
        ThrowIfDisposedOrNotOpen();
        message = null;
        bool timedout = false;
        try
        {
            message = this.Receive(timeout);
        }
        catch (TimeoutException)
        {
            timedout = true;
        }
        return (!timedout);
    }
```

CacheManager works. And I get the response Cache. But tryReceive run again and when I look Message. Message is closed. How can I fix that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved.

Tcp Binding add RelatesTo Header to Message. So code is changed to

```
public Message Receive(TimeSpan timeout)
{
    Message response = null;
    response = CommunicationCacheManager.Get(_request.Headers.Action, _request);

    if (response == null)
    {
        response = this.InnerChannel.Receive(timeout);
        int cacheTimeout = 0;
        if (response.Headers.FindHeader(Constants.CacheTimeOutHeader.NAME, Constants.CacheTimeOutHeader.NAMESPACE) > -1)
        {
            cacheTimeout = response.Headers.GetHeader<int>(Constants.CacheTimeOutHeader.NAME, Constants.CacheTimeOutHeader.NAMESPACE);
        }
        if (cacheTimeout > 0 && response != null &&
                !response.IsFault &&
                !response.IsEmpty)
        {
            CommunicationCacheManager.Add(_request.Headers.Action, cacheTimeout, ref response);
        }
    }
    else
    {
       response.Headers.RelatesTo=_request.Header.MessageId;
    }
    return response;
}
```